# Creating an APK using MSBuild command line error (PackageForAndroid or SignAndroidPackage)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

So I have been trying to create an APK in Release mode using the MSBuild command line executable.

Here is the contents of my batch file which I created:

```
ECHO Building DsdMobile Solution... >CON
cd "C:\Ross\DEVELOPMENT\HANDHELD\Android\Dsd Mobile MaterialDesign"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" DsdMobile.sln /P:Configuration=Release /v:quiet /t:Clean /nologo

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" DsdMobile.sln /P:Configuration=Release /v:quiet /t:Rebuild,PackageForAndroid /nologo
```

The first line I change the directory to my solution location.
Next, I do a Clean

Last, I do a Rebuild and PackageForAndroid (which I am expecting a ...apk file in my bin release folder. An apk is never created and I get an error.

The build is successful, but I get an error:

```
"C:Ross\Development\Handheld\Android\Dsd Mobile MaterialDesign\DsdMobile.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "PackageForAndroid" does not exists in the project. [C:\Ross\DEVELOPMENT\HANDHELD\Android\Dsd Mobile MaterialDesign\DsdMobile.sln]
```

I have also tried to use `SignAndroidPackage`'s `:t/` parameter, but this also fails with the same error:

```
"C:Ross\Development\Handheld\Android\Dsd Mobile MaterialDesign\DsdMobile.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "SignAndroidPackage" does not exists in the project. [C:\Ross\DEVELOPMENT\HANDHELD\Android\Dsd Mobile MaterialDesign\DsdMobile.sln]
```

The resource I have been using was from a PowerShell script:

https://gist.github.com/postb99/8319234

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try building the Android csproj file instead of the solution file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`/p:AndroidBuildApplicationPackage=true` instead of `/t:SignAndroidPackage`

See [Building Process - AndroidBuildApplicationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process)

Answer (score 3):

This works just fine for me from Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 command line prompts:

```
msbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release Application.Android.csproj
```

As already noted, build the csproj not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the solution, you will need to specify the project and task in the target e.g:

```
.WithTarget("DroidAppProj:SignAndroidPackage")
```

Here is more documentation:
Spoiler-it sux if you have a . in your project name:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2017

Comment: This is the correct way : .WithProperty("AndroidBuildApplicationPackage", "true")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the .sln rather than the .csproj, from the command line, you can do `/t:MyAndroidProject:SignAndroidPackage` where "MyAndroidProject" == the name of your Android project.

That will apply the target only to the specified csproj rather than trying to execute the target on every solution in the project.