# Build Pipeline issue for building xamarin Android project

Tags: xamarin

I am using the following configuration in my Azure build pipeline:

```
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  displayName: 'Build Android Project'
  inputs:
    projectFile: '$(solution)'
    outputDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Android'
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildVersionOption: 'latest'
    jdkOption: 'JDKVersion'
```

When I run the pipeline, I encounter the following error:
`Error MSB4057: The target "PackageForAndroid" does not exist in the project.`

This seems somewhat relevant, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to adjust in my pipeline configuration.

I'm not convinced by the suggestion to use the Android `.csproj` file instead of the solution file, as found in the following [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069480/creating-an-apk-using-msbuild-command-line-error-packageforandroid-or-signandro)

The build should be successful.

Comment: You should be pointing to the `.csproj` not the `.sln`

Comment: added as solution to your answer so you can accept that for future reference.

Comment: Package for android refers to the AAB file format package. Are you sur ethat is all configured properly? Try right clicking on your android project and selecting "Archive..." to test out locally.

Answer (score 0):

Your Azure Build Pipeline needs to point at your `.csproj` file and not your `.sln` file.

If you think about it, in Visual Studio, any time your perform a build, you're actually building the `.csproj` files and never the `.sln` file which is actually just a "container" for your different projects.